# Unable to copy anything to internal storage

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb, internal-storage, sony-xperia-z1

my phone is a Xperia Z1 Compact, with Android version 4.4.4 and no SD card in.
It's supposed to have around 1 Gb of free storage left, but when i connect it via USB to my pc i cannot copy any file to it. Windows shows me a "no free space available" dialog.
I recently ran out of space, but after i freed some (yes, i can delete) and cleared caches the problem arised.

Any clues?